# c - custom input, text overwrites when writing at the middle of a word in the command line

Tags: c, shell, input, termios

I'm writing a custom shell in C. I'm currently trying to get the user input.

I've put the terminal in raw mode:

```
term.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
term.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN);
term.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
term.c_cflag |= CS8;
term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

so that I can process arrow keys and other special keys.

The problem I have is that when I try to write something in the middle of a word, the text gets overwritten.

I get this:

[image]

But I need this:

[image]

Note: I initially have the string "abc", and with the cursor at 'b', I press 'z'. In my case, 'z' overwrites 'b', but I need it to be inserted between 'a' and 'b', and move "bc" to the right with one column.

Is there a flag in termios that I'm missing or I have to process everything the hard way?

Comment: *How* do you write? Do you go to a specific position and write the letter? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I basically write(STDIN_FILENO, "abc", 3), then I use termcap tgoto function to move the cursor, then I call another write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No termios flag. Instead you could consult termcap for [`im` capability string](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html#SEC32):

> `im`
>
> String of commands to enter insert mode. If the terminal has no special insert mode, but it can insert characters with a special command, `im` should be defined with a null value, because the `vi` editor assumes that insertion of a character is impossible if `im` is not provided. New programs should not act like `vi`. They should pay attention to `im` only if it is defined.

Comment: But there's still the problem with the word wrapping... And I can't really figure out a nice way to resolve it